# Multiple stellar-nodes not syncing

Tags: stellar-core

I am running a private network on a MAC laptop with 2 nodes

Node 1

```
HTTP_PORT=11626
PEER_PORT=11625
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
RUN_STANDALONE=false

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="My Network ; March 2018"
NODE_SEED="SB74UEA4WNFIJ57FR5HSRIH6RALKRYT35FOYUAVILVYRGZMCEHRKAS3B self"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

NODE_NAMES=[
 "GBA3P4H7CZ6NGWTKEXMLKRBCX2MO6SJT6FTADCEKNI6WIW6OO6EW2F5V two"
]
KNOWN_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11627"]
PREFERRED_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11627"]
PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS=["$two"]

FAILURE_SAFETY=0
CATCHUP_RECENT=60480
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true

[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=["$self", "$two"]

[HISTORY.local]
get="cp /Users/Harmit/Sites/two/historyarchive/{0} {1}"
put="cp {0} /Users/Harmit/Sites/two/historyarchive/{1}"
mkdir="mkdir -p /Users/Harmit/Sites/two/historyarchive/{0}"
```

Node 2

```
HTTP_PORT=11628
PEER_PORT=11627
PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
RUN_STANDALONE=false

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="My Network ; March 2018"

NODE_SEED="SBXIY3OI656HB7PQ76J26N3WCJ5LL3W3A43JGRC57IHMRJECLLZQFFPV self"
NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

COMMANDS=["ll?level=trace"]

NODE_NAMES=[
 "GAOQYRBOO3KR4OZZHEXROBJ5BQKDCSZGICU5Y5MF55IJBKVI3A5Q3RWC one"
]
KNOWN_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11625"]
PREFERRED_PEERS=["127.0.0.1:11625"]
PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS=["$one"]

FAILURE_SAFETY=0
UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
[QUORUM_SET]
VALIDATORS=["$self", "$one"]

[HISTORY.h1]
get="curl -sf http://one.localhost/~Harmit/one/historyarchive/{0} -o {1}"
```

Commands used to start the core server
Node 1

```
stellar-core --newhist local
stellar-core --newdb
stellar-core --forcescp
stellar-core
```

Node 2

```
stellar-core --newhist h1
stellar-core --newdb
stellar-core --forcescp
stellar-core
```

Question

1. Before starting the horizon server if I set INGEST=true, horizon
   server does not start it gives error  *ERRO[0001] import session
   failed: failed to load header: sql: no rows in result set INFO[0002]
   history db is empty, starting ingestion from ledger 0*

   This happens if there are 2 stellar core running on same machine. If
   single instance of stellar is running on a machine it works. Can we
   run multiple instances of stellar core and horizon on one machine
   (localhost)?
2. If I do not set INGEST=true horizon server starts up When i use
   stellar sdk to create account it hangs and times out after 30
   seconds. Cannot see any error on server. If I run the stellar-core in
   standalone mode it works as expected.

Output from node 1 stellar-core --c 'info':

```
2018-03-13T16:52:37.197 GAOQY [default INFO] {
   "info" : {
      "UNSAFE_QUORUM" : "UNSAFE QUORUM ALLOWED",
      "build" : "v9.2.0rc4-3-g589dcee0",
      "ledger" : {
         "age" : 1520985157,
         "baseFee" : 100,
         "baseReserve" : 100000000,
         "closeTime" : 0,
         "hash" : "0c2384cb563a178e56b9d596311bc298f5abe37f97f1b0b1b911f75a225fb574",
         "num" : 2,
         "version" : 0
      },
      "network" : "My Network ; March 2018",
      "peers" : {
         "authenticated_count" : 0,
         "pending_count" : 0
      },
      "protocol_version" : 9,
      "startedOn" : "2018-03-13T23:29:34Z",
      "state" : "Joining SCP"
   }
}

stellar-core --c 'quorum'
2018-03-13T16:55:37.066 GAOQY [default INFO] {
   "node" : "self",
   "slots" : {
      "2" : {
         "agree" : 0,
         "disagree" : null,
         "fail_at" : 0,
         "fail_with" : null,
         "hash" : "6d67a3",
         "missing" : [ "self", "two" ],
         "phase" : "unknown",
         "value" : {
            "t" : 2,
            "v" : [ "self", "two" ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Please let me know if I am missing any configuration / step. Multiple nodes on same physical mac laptop are not syncing; state is always "Joining SCP" and quorum has missing nodes

Can someone please help me resolve this issue. Appreciate all the help

Answer (score 3):

How about setting `ALLOW_LOCALHOST_FOR_TESTING=true` in your `.cfg` file?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue. In the configuration above $self was referring to secret seed instead of Account Id / Public Key. In addition updated configuration not to use alias like $self, $on3, $two ... instead used the Account id / Public Key directly.

Not an ideal configuration for production, for now it works for me in test. I am sure adding alias will work too. Will give it a try later.

Thanks

Comment: "$self" should work... At least it always works for me on Ubuntu. What else did you do, after replacing "$self" with the actual public key?

Comment: Yes I replaced with the actual public key. I agree $self will work, in my case i had accidentally assigned $self to the the private key.

Comment: Strange, I am using the same method to declare self: NODE_SEED="SBXIY3OI656HB7PQ76J26N3WCJ5LL3W3A43JGRC57IHMRJECLLZQFFPV self"... and it works for me